# Couldn't implement real-time user-to-user chat app in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, channel

I am newbie in web development and I working on one project and in this project, I have to create a real-time **user-to-user** chat application using **django rest framework**. I have implemented this in Django itself using **channels** package (created consumers, routing, templates, js files, and some other stuff), but I am stuck now, I don't know what to do. The goal is that I have to make an API in **DRF**, and Flutter devs should link it.

Here is my models.py

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    first_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
                                    blank=True, related_name='thread_first_person')
    second_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
                                    blank=True, related_name='thread_second_person')
    
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    objects = ThreadManager()
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['first_person', 'second_person']


class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chatmessage_thread')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

consumers.py

```
import json
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from chat.models import Thread, ChatMessage

User = get_user_model()


class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('connected', event)
        user = self.scope['user']
        chat_room = f'user_chatroom_{user.id}'
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print('receive', event)
        received_data = json.loads(event['text'])
        msg = received_data.get('message')
        sent_by_id = received_data.get('sent_by')
        send_to_id = received_data.get('send_to')
        thread_id = received_data.get('thread_id')

        if not msg:
            print('Error:: empty message')
            return False

        sent_by_user = await self.get_user_object(sent_by_id)
        send_to_user = await self.get_user_object(send_to_id)
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(thread_id)
        if not sent_by_user:
            print('Error:: sent by user is incorrect')
        if not send_to_user:
            print('Error:: send to user is incorrect')
        if not thread_obj:
            print('Error:: Thread id is incorrect')

        await self.create_chat_message(thread_obj, sent_by_user, msg)

        other_user_chat_room = f'user_chatroom_{send_to_id}'
        self_user = self.scope['user']
        response = {
            'message': msg,
            'sent_by': self_user.id,
            'thread_id': thread_id
        }

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            other_user_chat_room,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'text': json.dumps(response)
            }
        )

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.chat_room,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'text': json.dumps(response)
            }
        )



    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print('disconnect', event)

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        print('chat_message', event)
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'text': event['text']
        })

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user_object(self, user_id):
        qs = User.objects.filter(id=user_id)
        if qs.exists():
            obj = qs.first()
        else:
            obj = None
        return obj

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, thread_id):
        qs = Thread.objects.filter(id=thread_id)
        if qs.exists():
            obj = qs.first()
        else:
            obj = None
        return obj

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_chat_message(self, thread, user, msg):
        ChatMessage.objects.create(thread=thread, user=user, message=msg)
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

messages.js

```
let input_message = $('#input-message')
let message_body = $('.msg_card_body')
let send_message_form = $('#send-message-form')
const USER_ID = $('#logged-in-user').val()

let loc = window.location
let wsStart = 'ws://'

if(loc.protocol === 'https') {
    wsStart = 'wss://'
}
let endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname

var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint)

socket.onopen = async function(e){
    console.log('open', e)
    send_message_form.on('submit', function (e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let message = input_message.val()
        let send_to = get_active_other_user_id()
        let thread_id = get_active_thread_id()

        let data = {
            'message': message,
            'sent_by': USER_ID,
            'send_to': send_to,
            'thread_id': thread_id
        }
        data = JSON.stringify(data)
        socket.send(data)
        $(this)[0].reset()
    })
}

socket.onmessage = async function(e){
    console.log('message', e)
    let data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    let message = data['message']
    let sent_by_id = data['sent_by']
    let thread_id = data['thread_id']
    newMessage(message, sent_by_id, thread_id)
}

socket.onerror = async function(e){
    console.log('error', e)
}

socket.onclose = async function(e){
    console.log('close', e)
}


function newMessage(message, sent_by_id, thread_id) {
    if ($.trim(message) === '') {
        return false;
    }
    let message_element;
    let chat_id = 'chat_' + thread_id
    if(sent_by_id == USER_ID){
        message_element = `
            <div class="d-flex mb-4 replied">
                <div class="msg_cotainer_send">
                    ${message}
                    <span class="msg_time_send">8:55 AM, Today</span>
                </div>
                <div class="img_cont_msg">
                    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg">
                </div>
            </div>
        `
    }
    else{
        message_element = `
           <div class="d-flex mb-4 received">
              <div class="img_cont_msg">
                 <img src="https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/001292/481/WV/_D.jpg" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg">
              </div>
              <div class="msg_cotainer">
                 ${message}
              <span class="msg_time">8:40 AM, Today</span>
              </div>
           </div>
        `

    }

    let message_body = $('.messages-wrapper[chat-id="' + chat_id + '"] .msg_card_body')
    message_body.append($(message_element))
    message_body.animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 100);
    input_message.val(null);
}


$('.contact-li').on('click', function (){
    $('.contacts .actiive').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')

    // message wrappers
    let chat_id = $(this).attr('chat-id')
    $('.messages-wrapper.is_active').removeClass('is_active')
    $('.messages-wrapper[chat-id="' + chat_id +'"]').addClass('is_active')

})

function get_active_other_user_id(){
    let other_user_id = $('.messages-wrapper.is_active').attr('other-user-id')
    other_user_id = $.trim(other_user_id)
    return other_user_id
}

function get_active_thread_id(){
    let chat_id = $('.messages-wrapper.is_active').attr('chat-id')
    let thread_id = chat_id.replace('chat_', '')
    return thread_id
}
```

**Summary**:
How I can skip front side (js, templates) and built not regular Django project but make an API of user-to-user chat app using DRF

Comment: Hi. Please explain your problem better by showing the code you have implemented till now and asking exactly what you need

Comment: Have a look at Django Channels and WebSockets.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your attention. I have read twice the doc of django channels, but they didn't mention, how we can use channels with drf.